# Google Analytics (V4) - APP_TRACKER,GLOBAL_TRACKER and ECOMMERCE_TRACKER

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to use the Google Analytics V4. I got the following code from the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#next-steps

They are discussing about APP_TRACKER,GLOBAL_TRACKER and ECOMMERCE_TRACKER. What are these and what is the significance of this.

```
      synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
            if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

              GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
              Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                  : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                      : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
              mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

            } 

            return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just to demonstrate that you can provide different `Tracker` objects for different uses. Also it demonstrates that you can create them exclusively in code or create them from XML files. The `Tracker` is used to send events to Google.

Comment: So in the code, what they are trying to do. They will prefer the APP tracker first if not they will go for global tracker and then ecommerce tracker right ?  So we can use Tracker t =   analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID), if we want to use the APP tracking alone.

Comment: The `getTracker(...)` method is just an example of different approaches. You must pass the type of `Tracker` you want to the method, for example `getTracker( TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER)`. You may only need one `Tracker` type, so you may want to change the method to just return a single `Tracker` type.